Set Focus on Input
I have Angular code where the first field needs focus when the page loads. The challenge is, inputs appear dynamically based on conditions, and they're in both the main and nested components. How can I set focus on all these inputs?
I have tried to create a service, directive and included @ViewChild() decorator

Add the #input to all the fields that might need focus.
then take a view child of the HTML like so
@ViewChild('input') input!: ElementRef<any>;

Then this view child will contain the reference of the first visible input and we can just call the focus method, on ngAfterViewInit!
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.input?.nativeElement?.focus();
}


Will it work for both the main component inputs and the nested ones? There are a lot of both types.

@coder try it for a few fields first, them implement it for all, if not try to use ViewChildren then access the first element and focus it!

I don't know much about angular, but shouldn't you just use a 'querySelector' to find the first input tag?


document.querySelector('input').focus()
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>first input</p>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <p>second input</p>
    <input type="text">
  </body>
 </html>



When you run this snippet, the input tag located at the top is focused regardless of whether it is a parent or not.

yeah this won't be helpful in my case because I have inputs inside nested(child) components too
